# jQuery Mobile "popup" div is not hidden?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I was working with jQuery Mobile and hoping to use the `popup` method. Previously everything was working but when having to refactor my code something has gone wrong and now I've spent so long looking at this I really can't see the "wood for the trees". Thus in my application, I created a test page, removed all my JS and CSS and HTML from it and thus had a stark but clean page. I've even gone so far that I've added the JQuery examples and link to their hosted scripts in case there is a conflict due to my code... but still my problem remains... the DIV used for the popup isn't originally hidden and clicking on the buttons does nothing... I've really got myself worked up on this and I'm sure I've missed something really simple and obvious (perhaps I should go take a coffee for 15 mins)...

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#basic" data-rel="popup" data-role="button">Default popup</a>
<div id="basic" data-role="popup" class="ui-content">
  <p>I am a default popup</p>
</div>

<a href="#transitionExample" data-transition="none" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="popup">No transition</a>
<a href="#transitionExample" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="popup">Pop</a>
<a href="#transitionExample" data-transition="slideup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="popup">Slide up</a>
<a href="#transitionExample" data-transition="slidedown" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="popup">Slide down</a>
<div id="transitionExample" data-role="popup" data-transition="flip">
  <p>This is some text for the transition example</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is a screenshot in Firefox (it's the same when deploying to a test device)

[image]

What am I doing wrong... I can feel an emotional moment coming soon...

Comment: Where is the popup initialization js code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the [popup widget](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html) has been officially released. Perhaps what you meant to use is a [dialog](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html)?

If you want to use the popup dialog you will need to link to the correct version of JQM, in addition i don't think you need to place a class of `ui-content` on the div, from the docs

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div>
```

If you mean to use it with a dialog then your markup is slightly off, your links/buttons should be in their own page and the dialogs in their own divs (i.e not nested in the page with the links).

Here's the fixed up markup

```
<div data-role="page">
<a href="#basic" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button">Default popup</a>

<a href="#transitionExample" data-transition="none" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog">No transition</a>
<a href="#transitionExample" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog">Pop</a>
<a href="#transitionExample" data-transition="slideup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog">Slide up</a>
<a href="#transitionExample" data-transition="slidedown" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog">Slide down</a>
</div>

<div id="basic" data-role="dialog">
<div data-role="header"><h3></h3></div>
<div  data-role="content" >
<p>I am a default popup</p>
</div>

</div>

<div id="transitionExample" data-role="dialog">
<div data-role="header"><h3></h3></div>
<div data-role="content">
  <p>This is some text for the transition example</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is odd as in a previous version of my file all was working... I've also noticed a change in the documentation from jQuery... strange! I can't really use the dialog as it was clashing (for some reason) with another element on my page (a canvas element).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm just going to use the dialog and use an anchor instead of linking to a file, this should do the job and prevent the clash with my canvas.

Comment: I don't think the popup has ever been part of the stable release. Is your canvas element on the dialog/popup? I'm not sure why JQM should clash with your  canvas, I have a JQM app with a canvas element and its working fine,

Comment: I think the question is a valid one and doesn't refer to *pages* opened with `data-rel="dialog"` Check out http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/popup-images.html where you have a `<div data-role="popup">` which is not it's own page. In Chrome this div is hidden and pops up nicely. In Safari (iPhone) the div is not hidden.

Comment: @Marc This question is referring to jQuery Mobile 1.1 and was asked before JQM 1.2 (and with it the popup widget) was released.

Comment: OK, it's just that Mike's syntax is definitely the popup feature. I've posted an updated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404211/popup-not-hidden-on-iphone-in-jquery-mobile-1-3-1/