# Popup not hidden on iPhone in jQuery Mobile 1.3.1

Tags: jquery-mobile

According to the [documentation for jQuery Mobile 1.2](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/popup-images.html) it should be possible to make arbitrary divs popup without them being pages:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupHelp">I should be hidden</div>

Until <a href="#popupHelp" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">this</a> is clicked!
```

This seems to work fine in Chrome on the PC: The div is hidden until `this` is clicked and the popup is displayed.

On the iPhone however the div is displayed (with X close button) below the page footer before the link is clicked.

Is this a bug or some legacy code not supported in JQM 1.3.1?

PS: I'm aware this question has been asked but no appropriate answer was given.

Comment: Do it have the code inside page div or outside? Popups should be placed inside page div and dialogs outside.

Comment: [Here's the docs you actually wanted](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/)

Comment: Inside content divs Omar; Ta Blazemonger!

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the jQM popup is still pretty finicky.  Make sure your popup div is defined *within* your page's content div (`<div data-role="content">`).

Comment: It always was but "finicky" is the WORD - in 10 experiments, I've seen about 3 different behaviours.

Comment: For sure.  I definitely prefer the look of the popup, but I've begrudgingly replaced some of my popups with dialogs due to erratic popup behavior.